# Regular Expressions - Javascript - Single Quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

Lets assume we have a couple variables. A. Str, a string, `John's`.... B. regex expression as shown below.

`inner.Html` DOES have `John's` in it.

What I dont get, is this code for regex never works when I have a str with a single quote in it. Any ideas?

```
var str = "John's"   
var regex = new RegExp("\>[^\<]+?(" + str  +")[^\>]+?\<", "gi");
var thismatch = regex.exec(this.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Please provide your input (innerhtml) test values

Comment: yes, what is your innerHtml look like? It appears you are trying to match against this "><John's><"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what your outer element looks like, but one main thing missing and the reason why your regex will not work when **str** has a single quote is because you need to escape the quote in the string.

```
var str = "John's".replace(/(\')/g, '\\$1'); // "John\'s";
var regex = new RegExp("\>[^\<]+?(" + str  +")[^\>]+?\<", "gi");
var thismatch = regex.exec(this.innerHTML);
```